# Drupal 8.x before action middleware

Tags: php, symfony, drupal-8

I have been trying to implement a before-action middleware for a module on Drupal 8.x by following this guide from [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html). However, when getting the `$controller` variable from the event, it seems to always be a `Closure` object which I am unable to use `instanceof` to identify the controller. I have found 2 ways of doing it with some pros and cons on each.

1. Instead of getting the controller from the event, I can get the request instead then use the `ControllerResolver` to get the controller. This seems to give me the right controller. However, the `HttpKernel`'s `ControllerResolver` seems to conflict with some internals of Drupal which breaks other parts of Drupal. As for the `ControllerResolver` from Drupal, I can't seem to figure out the arguments that needs to be passed in the constructors.
2. By using PHP Reflection, I can get the static variables of the `Closure` where the controller object is located. However, I don't know if that's the only type of object that can be passed making this solution risky.

Is there a more idiomatic way to do it in Drupal? What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: How do you get the `$controller` var from the event? `$event->getController()` and then `$controller[0]` (should contain the class, not an closure) or something else?

Comment: I am using `$event->getController()`. Normally in Symfony it returns an array of the controller and the methods name I think, but in Drupal, it seems to return a closure.